# Search and replace colon (:) between double quotes using regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am fairly new to regular expression therefore this may be the simplest question you've seen on StackOverflow :-)

I have a large JSON file with text like this:

`{..., "text": "BLAH BLAH", ...}`

The text may contain any of the special characters and also characters like `\"`, which I understand can be seen as escape character in regular expression. I am trying to find and replace a single character colon `:` with tilde `~` within the portion followed by `"text"` preferably in Notepad++. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will find all the `:` in the value for fields named `text` and replace the character with a `~`. Note there were issues using regular expressions with Notepad++ v5. My demo here was tested in Notepad++ v6.3.3

Regex: `("text":\s"[^"]*?):`

Replace with: `$1~`

Input string: `{"not text": "12:34", "text": "BLAH:BLAH", "Never get a": ":oskupee"}`

[image]

Comment: Will this work for `"text": "I have a : "Saying" about something, which matters at 6:00PM"`

Comment: Sorry the best we're going to be able to is an expression like this `("text":\s"(?:(?!"}|",\s"\w+":\s").)*):` which you'd need to run multiple times until Notepad reported no more changes made. Unfortunatly this type of expression is beyond the reach of Notepad as it doesn't support something in the expression. Generally speaking this expression does work http://regexr.com?35b69.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did (thanks for all the help @Mike, but I had to make many edits. That's why I am answering my own question so other users can get the complete answer)

1. Search for `\"text\": \".*? : .*?\",` in Notepad++
2. Find and replace with `\1~\2` to replace all `:` with `~`
3. Manually correct the mistakes

Comment: In notepad++ Given text `{"text": "BLAH : BLAH", "Never get a": ":oskupee", "not text": "12:34"}`, this expression yields `{~ "Never get a": ":oskupee", "not text": "12:34"}`

Comment: Also in notepad++ Given text `{"text": "BLAH:BLAH", "Never get a": " : oskupee", "not text": "12:34"}`, this expression yields `{~ "not text": "12:34"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
find: ("(?:[^"]+|(?<=\\)")*")\s*:
replace: $1~
```

The idea is to capture the content inside double quotes, to put it in the replacement.

I use a lookbehind to allow escaped double quotes inside double quotes.